# Latex : Bibliography in french - plainnat-fr

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, french, bibliographystyle

I am using the following template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-project-report-or-memoire/zcgzvcmrsxsb

Moreover, I am using `plainnat-fr` for styling the bibliography, as I need the latter to be in **french** (e.g. dans instead if in,  etc.).

My main issue is that I cannot break a citation inside the text ending up in hbox errors (=> citations leaking out of paragraphs). What's more the `et al.` option does not seem to work correctly :

Having the following citation :

```
    @inproceedings{nooralahzadeh_part_2014,
    address = {Dublin, Ireland},
    title = {Part of {Speech} {Tagging} for {French} {Social} {Media} {Data}},
    url = {https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C14-1166},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of {COLING} 2014, the 25th {International} {Conference} on {Computational} {Linguistics}: {Technical} {Papers}},
    publisher = {Dublin City University and Association for Computational Linguistics},
    author = {Nooralahzadeh, Farhad and Brun, Caroline and Roux, Claude},
    month = aug,
    year = {2014},
    pages = {1764--1772},
}
```

We would expect something like `Nooralahzadeh et al.(2014)` .

Instead I am getting : `[Nooralahzadeh et al.(2014)Nooralahzadeh, Brun, et Roux]`.

Any recommendations and any help would be very much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It looks like you have failed to load the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using it but I get the following error (in other citations as well):
`Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> \unskip  l.30  \cite{corblin:ijn_00550962}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Comment: So I went with biblatex in Overleaf.

Comment: Are you loading both `natbib` and `cite`? If so, that would be a mistake.

Comment: No I am not loading `natbib` since I had the errors previously stated. I tried it as an alternative to `cite`.

Comment: The `cite` citation management package is designed to generate numeric-style citation call-outs, whereas the `plainnat-fr` bibliography style outputs authoryear-style citation call-outs. It's a plain and simple mistake to employ the `cite` package here. About the error message you're getting for the `corblin:ijn_00550962` entry: I'd check it for syntax errors, such as missing opening and closing curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following compilable version of your code snippets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{nooralahzadeh_part_2014,
    address   = {Dublin, Ireland},
    title     = {{Part of Speech Tagging for French Social Media Data}},
    url       = {https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C14-1166},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of COLING 2014, the 25th International Conference on Computational Linguistics: Technical Papers},
    publisher = {Dublin City University and Association for Computational Linguistics},
    author    = {Nooralahzadeh, Farhad and Brun, Caroline and Roux, Claude},
    month     = aug,
    year      = {2014},
    pages     = {1764--1772},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-fr}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{nooralahzadeh_part_2014}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Observe that the instruction `\usepackage{natbib}` is commented out. If I run a full compile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- I get the following citation call-out:

[image]

That seems to be an *exact match* to what what you posted in your query, doesn't it?

In contrast, after activating `\usepackage{natbib}` and running LaTeX twice more, I get:

[image]

This looks like what you should be expecting, doesn't it?

In short, do try loading the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: According to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274751/missing-endcsname-inserted-with-babel-and-natbib I should have loaded `natbib` before `babel` ! Now it's working perfectly like you suggested to :) .

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to accept your answer. PS. I have edited the position of `natbib`. Everything works now. Thank you !

Comment: @Marrluxia - Glad you found a solution that works for you. (Incidentally, in the sample code I posted above, `babel` gets loaded before `natbib`, *without* any ill effects. The posting you found is more than six years old by now; I'd look twice before jumping to the conclusion that it's still up to date.) Incidentally, while you may not have enough rep points yet to *upvote* a posting, you don't need any rep points to *accept* an answer to a query you posted.

Comment: yes, totally forgot! I accepted your answer. The template itself hasn't been updated for the last 7 years, so maybe it has to do something with the other dependencies/packages ? I am not sure. Thank you again !